# Can I use the dustproof Coolpix w300 with SB 800 speed lights?

Tags: nikon, flash, wireless-flash

I am very interested in the [Coolpix w300](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/compact-digital-cameras/coolpix-w300.html) because of its dustproof feature.

But I need it to work with my sb800 speedlights. Will it preflash in commander mode? Also will it work with my shutter remote?

Comment: What kind of shutter remote do you have? WIred? Infrared? Radio + wired receiver? Etc.

Comment: Looks like it's compatible only with one of these lights: https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/compact-digital-cameras/coolpix-w300.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-CompatibleWith

Answer (score 2):

http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/354/COOLPIX_W300.html

That is the w300 manual.  The flash does not have a hot shoe, and the manual does not mention CLS or Commander or any type of remote flash use.   Page 51 says the internal flash has flash modes of Auto or Off.  Not even a Manual flash mode to trigger an optical slave.

Dustproof does not seem the best description. The camera is a waterproof camera for use up to 100 feet underwater, but it would seem to be one of the worst choices for a remote speedlight like the SB-800.  I think it's unlikely any compact would have Commander mode, so for remote use of the SB-800 (in SU-4 mode), you would at least want Manual flash mode so you could trigger it.  Some compact cameras offer Manual flash mode.  Manual flash mode is manual, NOT auto, you have to set the correct power level in the SB-800 yourself.

Comment: Nikon describes the camera as "Waterproof, freezeproof, shockproof and dustproof adventure camera".